# Grails 3 command line's commands source code

Tags: grails, grails3, grails3.2.0, grails-3.2

Where I can find the Grails 3.2.11 command line source code files?

When you execute the command `grails help` it displays a list of commands:

```
| Available Commands (type grails help 'command-name' for more info):
| Command Name                          Command Description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
create-command                          Creates an Application Command
create-controller                       Creates a controller
create-domain-class                     Creates a Domain Class
create-functional-test                  Creates a Geb Functional Test
create-integration-test                 Creates an integration test
create-interceptor                      Creates an interceptor
create-scaffold-controller              Creates a scaffolded controller
create-script                           Creates a Grails script
create-service                          Creates a Service
create-taglib                           Creates a Tag Library
create-unit-test                        Creates a unit test
dependency-report                       Prints out the Grails application's dependencies
```

For example the `grails dependency-report`. Where I can find its source code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After a while I found the source code here: https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/tree/master/profiles/base/commands